# Issue with Testcafe: withText is not a function

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

noob coder here, not pretending to be anything else.

I'm trying to write a selector in Testcafe, and according to the documentation (so far as I have understood it) this should work, however it returns an error:

```
await t.click(Selector('span').withtext('Pending Applications').find(a.field-link.external-link))
```

The error it returns is

```
TypeError: (0 , _exportableLib.Selector)(...).withtext is not a function
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is small typo in your code. You have to use 'withText()' instead of 'withtext().

```
 await t.click(Selector('span').withText('Pending Applications').find('a.field-link.external-link'))
```